# Can you access NEST camera stream programmatically?

Tags: nest-api

I'm able to authorize against the NEST API for a user, and I can get notified of movement events, but I want to download a movie of the event programmatically.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the event, the API will surface a link to download an image or an animated gif of the event. The URL will be in the `last_event` bucket. The link currently is available for users who have a Nest Aware subscription.

Reference: https://developer.nest.com/documentation/api-reference/overview#last_event-cam